# Deploying application on tomcat server through netbeans

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, netbeans

I am trying to create a new JSF application in Netbeans. I have transferred my existing java source code files & packages to newly created src folder in the new 'Java Web project with JSF framework' in netbeans & also I have added all the dependencies to the classpath.

But when I try to deploy my application on the Tomcat server through netbeans, it fails with following error

```
Starting Tomcat process...
Waiting for Tomcat...
Tomcat server started.
In-place deployment at Z:\dev\Px10App\build\web
deploy?config=file%3A%2FZ3A%2FUsers%2FXX%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext64443165856331944.xml&path=/Px10App
http://localhost:8070/manager/deploy?config=file%3A%2FZ%3A%2FUsers%2FXX%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext64443165856331944.xml&path=/Px10App
Z:\dev\Px10App\nbproject\build-impl.xml:732: The module has not been deployed.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 minute 19 seconds)
```

Any help on resolving this is highly appreciated !

Comment: From where did you copy the files? I mean were you using some other IDE before and now trying to go to the NetBeans? Does your NetBeans project show any error? Did you try restarting the NetBeans once?

Comment: The decoded version of the first url seems incorrect: file:/Z3A/Users/XX/AppData/Local/Temp/context64443165856331944.xml 
(Notice the missing % Before 3A)

Comment: @Bhushan: No I just copied the src files from another project in netbeans to the new project with jsf support enabled. Yes I've tried restarting it several times

Comment: @Marcos: Check for the hidden files. Those might have come along with required src as well.

Comment: @Bhushan: I have taken care of that. Btw I just found that I'm able to upload it on Glassfish server but not on Tomcat.

Comment: yes! its working now on glassfish!

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, Your project runs fine using **Glassfish.** The most logical idea behind your problem is that your Tomcat container does not have the required libraries.
Glassfish comes along shipped with all the necessary **libraries** for a JSF based web application or an EJB App (e.g : **jsf-imp**l, Mysql connector, **`jsf-api`,** mojarra impl, the list is long).

You can try copying these libraries in the LIB folder of your tomcat and restart it.
Tell us the news.